# Simple DOM html parser read html table

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, html-table

I am trying to read specific values of this HTML table via a php dom parser. I want my code to only read the "td width" tags and output only these items from the table and look like this:

" WAITLIST, 91630, ACCY 2001, 10, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, Duques 251, 9:35AM-10:50AM, 01/13/14-04/28/14 "

Here is the HTML table:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#006699">
                                <tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font">
                                    <td width="7%">WAITLIST</td>
                                    <td width="5%">91630</td>
                                    <td width="11%">
                ACCY <A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~bulletin/ugrad/accy.html#2001" target="_blank">2001</A>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="5%">10</td>
                                    <td width="16%">Intro Financial Accounting</td>
                                    <td width="6%">3.00</td>
                                    <td width="8%"> Zou, Y</td>
                                    <td width="8%"><A HREF="http://www.gwu.edu/~map/building.cfm?BLDG=DUQUES" target="_blank" >DUQUES</a> 251</td>
                                    <td width="13%">TR<br>09:35AM - 10:50AM</td>
                                    <td width="14%">
                                        01/13/14 - 04/28/14
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="7%">

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                                     </table
```

Here is my php code which grabs the whole table, some elements of which I don't want in my output, and repeats the output multiple times:

```
 // Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('testdata.html');

foreach($html->find('table') as $e){
foreach($html->find('td') as $f){
    echo $f->innertext . '<br>';
    }
    }
```

How can I change my code to only grab and output these elements:
"WAITLIST, 91630, ACCY 2001, 10, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Zou, Y, Duques 251, 9:35AM-10:50AM, 01/13/14-04/28/14"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('testdata.html');

foreach($html->find('table') as $e){
    foreach($e->find('td') as $f){
        echo strip_tags($f->innertext) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

You were pretty close already...

Forgot about the tag. See if strip_tags works for you.

https://www.php.net/strip_tags